# Combine result from two SQL queries from different instances, not linkeable

Tags: powershell

I have two queries executed on different SQL instances. I must execute them as two separate queries.

I need to combine the results from these into one, so that I can create a CSV file with all rows from $result, when there is a match in $lookup. The match is made by comparing columns named ID in both.

The CSV file should have all columns from $result, plus all columns from matching row in $lookup, except for ID.

The column names are not known, except for ID which is in both.

To create the CSV I plan on using Export-CSV. But I need to combine the two results somehow.

```
$result = @(Invoke-Sqlcmd –ServerInstance $ServerInstance –Database $Database -ErrorVariable sqlerr -OutputSqlErrors $true -Query $sql -QueryTimeout 0 -ErrorAction Stop | select *)
$lookup = @(Invoke-Sqlcmd –ServerInstance $ServerInstance –Database $Database -ErrorVariable sqlerr -OutputSqlErrors $true -Query $sql -QueryTimeout 0 -ErrorAction Stop | select *)
```

I have tried for example this:

```
($result | select *) | Join ($lookup | select *) -on ID -eq ID
```

EDIT: Got it working, answer below.

Comment: Have you considered using linked servers? Then you can inner join both datasets in 1 query.

Comment: Yes, but that is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I swithced to using "System.Data.SqlClient" when fetching the data.
Then the code below worked.
Thank you LotPings for pointing me in the right direction.

```
 $resultCols = ($result.Columns | ForEach-Object {$_.ColumnName})
 $AppendCols = ($lookup.Columns | ForEach-Object {$_.ColumnName})
 $AppendCols = $AppendCols | Where-Object {$_ -ne 'ID'}

 $AllCols = $resultCols + $AppendCols

 $result = $result | Select-Object -Property $AllCols
 $output = @()

 foreach($Row in $result)
 {
     $lookupIDRow = $lookup | Where-Object ID -eq $Row.ID
     if($lookupIDRow)
     {
         foreach($Col in $AppendCols)
         {
             $Row.$Col = $lookupIDRow.$Col
         }

         $output+=$Row
     }
 }
```

Comment: `$Output` will only contain merged Rows, is this intended? Otherwise Rows without matching `ID` in `$lookup` would have $null as value in the appended columns.

Comment: Yes only matching rows should be output. I haven't verified that part yet but that is the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest something along this:

- enumerate columns of `$result` and `$lookup`
- determine columns to add
- extend `$result` with these columns
- iterate rows of `$result` get matching row of `$lookup`
- insert values

Untested script:

```
## the following commands are incomplete (missing closing parenthesis)
# $result = @(Invoke-Sqlcmd –ServerInstance $ServerInstance –Database $Database -ErrorVariable sqlerr -OutputSqlErrors $true -Query $sql -QueryTimeout 0 -ErrorAction Stop | select *
# $lookup = @(Invoke-Sqlcmd –ServerInstance $ServerInstance –Database $Database -ErrorVariable sqlerr -OutputSqlErrors $true -Query $sql -QueryTimeout 0 -ErrorAction Stop | select *

$resultCols = $result.PsObject.Properties.Name
$AppendCols = $lookup.PsObject.Properties.Name | Where Name -notin $resultCols

$result = $result | Select-Object -Property *,$AppendCols

foreach($Row in $result){
    $lookupID = $lookup | Where-Object ID -eq $Row.ID
    if($lookupID){
        foreach($Col in $AppendCols){
            $Row.$Col = $lookupID.$Col
        }
    }
}
$result | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation .\ExtendedResult.csv
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get an error from "$Row[$Col] = $lookupID[$Col]": 
Unable to index into an object of type System.Management.Automation.PSObject.

Comment: Please try with `$Row.$Col = $lookupID.$Col` instead

Comment: Thanks! That uncovered a previous error from "$result = $result | Select-Object -Property *, $AppendCols"
"Select-Object : Cannot convert System.Object[] to one of the following types {System.String, System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock}.
"

Comment: What type,content do `$resultCols`,`$lookupCols` have?

Comment: BaseType: System.Array

Comment: ATM I've no sql server at hand to drill down `$result|Get-Member` to see what properties are accessible

Comment: I modified your code some and got it working. Posting the code in case someone is interested. Tank you LotPings for getting me started!

Comment: To be of use for future readers, feel free to edit my answer or present your own.